# Get objects / functions from SAP BEx (Business Explorer) Analyzer Excel add-in

Tags: excel, add-in, sap-bw

I work with an Excel add-in called SAP BEx Analyzer (`BExAnalyzer.xla`).

Unfortunately, the documentation of this add-in seems very incomplete and it's a pain to work with it.

I would like to know if there is a way to inspect such an add-in to see what objects/methods/function and so on it contains?

Many thanks!

Comment: You will have to look at the addin code - and it is 99.9% likley the addin will be locked with a password. There are ways around this, suggest you look further at SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the current release of SAP Business Explorer (based on 7.30), the `BExAnalyzer.xla` file is unprotected so you are able to inspect it.

If you wish to delve deeper in to the BEx object model, it is worth adding a reference in your VBA Project to the two type libraries (`BExAddin.tlb` and `BExApi.tlb`) in the Business Explorer installation folder (usually located in `\Program Files (x86)\SAP\Business Explorer\BI\`).

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually in the exact same boat with BEx. I haven't found any official documentation but a hefty amount of google fu gets me by. I've also had some luck pressing `F2` in the code window when you have the `SAPBEX.xla` module selected and then picking the SAPBEX library in the first drop down. It will give you all the methods/functions/constants in the library which isn't documented well at all either but you can make some educated guesses and trial and error...if you have the spare time.

Comment: Thx for the hint, but unfortunately the "F2-docs" don't contain, for example, the Items-property of the BEx-object (Set BEx1 = Application.Run("BExAnalyzer.xla!GetBEx") Set BExItems = BEx1.Items )